# Multiple sprites for a prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

Im making a japanese educational game and made this [sprite sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdpMY.jpg) Ive already sliced it in the sprite editor and named all the symbols.

Im instantiating 5 prefabs that need to have 5 different sprites with different 
symbols. I thought I was gonna be able to either assign the entire sheet to a game object or just keep adding sprite renderers to the game object, but I was wrong.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: [Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) might be of more help

Answer (score 2):

You can change the sprite directly from code.

```
this.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = someSprite;
```

You can dependency inject the sprites themselves using the editor and a public variable for each; or if you prefer, you can use `Resources.Load` instead.